# Using region digraph bundle of equinox project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, equinox

I'm trying to use region digraph bundle of equinox in my project. As first step, I'm trying to test the bundle **org.eclipse.equinox.region** using **org.eclipse.equinox.region.tests** bundle exists in [equinox project](http://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.bundles.git/tree/bundles).

When I import the relevant bundles to Eclipse IDE, I get error in loading **org.eclipse.core.tests.harness.PerformanceTestRunner** package in **RegionPerformanceTests** class. This caused because I couldn't import the above package in the manifest file. When I try to add it as dependency in manifest file, This package is not there to be added. I couldn't find any packages given in this link when I add dependencies given [in this link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Automated_Testing)

It will be really helpful if I can get some help regarding this issue.